# How to make android library uses-permission optional instead of required

Tags: android, android-manifest, manifest, android-library

One of the libraries I am using specifies:

```xml
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
```

But I am handling the case where the camera is not available so I'd like to make it required="false".

Currently I am just removing it completely with

```xml
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" tools:node="remove" />
```

in my manifest file.  That's not ideal because then it doesn't show up in the merged manifest at all.  How do I get it to appear in the merged manifest file as

```xml
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" tools:replace="required" />
```

`tools:replace` [replaces a lower-priority attribute](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge#attribute_markers) and so should give you what you want.